# Formatting JavaScript for Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com) the [leaflet-js' gem](https://github.com/cfis/leaflet-js), but can't figure out the syntax to get the map to show.

```
<div id="map">
  <%=
  var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
  mapLink = 
      '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
  L.tileLayer(
      'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; ' + mapLink,
      maxZoom: 18,
      }).addTo(map);
  %>
</div>
```

produces the error `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::L`. What is the correct formatting and is there a guide on how to translate regular javascript for use with Rails? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using `<%=` which is for embedded Ruby to use JavaScript.

The Ruby interpreter is thus trying to read your code as if it was Ruby, hence the error.

Try something like:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
  var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
  mapLink = 
      '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
  L.tileLayer(
      'http://<%= s %>.tile.openstreetmap.org/<%= z %>/<%= x %>/<%= y %>.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; ' + mapLink,
      maxZoom: 18,
      }).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Comment: I think having it interpreted is the point. Here's code for another gem https://github.com/axyjo/leaflet-rails and I'm looking for similar for leaflet-js.

    <%= map(:center => {
      :latlng => [51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283],
      :zoom => 18
    }) %>

Comment: Leaflet-js contains basically the assets for Leaflet, whereas Leaflet-rails has view helpers. If you continue using leaflet-js, you may have to write a view helper.

Comment: Reuben: Thanks, I didn't get that was the difference. So I need a view helper to run in in Rails. In my newbie state, I assumed since it was a gem it was meant to work in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not adding much, except to say now I get the difference between the two gems.  The Leaflet-rails helper gem gets the syntax slightly wrong and therefore doesn't work. This (almost) works

```
<div id="map">
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([<%= @location.latitude %>, <%= @location.longitude %>], 16);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
              maxZoom: 19,
    }).addTo(map);
        marker = L.marker([<%= @location.latitude %>, <%= @location.longitude %>]).addTo(map)
  </script>
</div>
```

I still need to work on the marker. Only shows a question mark.

Thanks for the help